# Getting a onclick on a linkbutton

Tags: sharepoint, onclick, linkbutton

I'm working on a webpart for sharepoint 2013.

But i'm having a problem.

While coding the .ascx.cs file

What I have to do is :
I have a custom list with a title, a link to a video and a photo

I need to put the title in a webpart and when you click on it , it has to play the video on the same page using htm5 (so when I click on the title I need to get the link to put in the html5 code)

I have the the title but I can not get an onclick on my linkbutton.

my code so far :

```
public VisualWebPart1()
        {

            // Get the list
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://my.uwsp.local/sites/Video/");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();                
            SPList list = web.Lists["VideoLijst"];
            SPView view = list.DefaultView;

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
            StringCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                i = i + 1;


                LinkButton lnBtn = new LinkButton();
                lnBtn.Text = (list.GetItemById(i).Title.ToString()) + " ";
                lnBtn.ToolTip = i.ToString();
                Controls.Add(lnBtn);

            }

        }


protected void LnBtn_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
```

But I can't get a `onclick` on the linkbutton
`lnBtn.Click += lnBtn();` doesn't work

Comment: Does `lnBtn.Click += LnBtn_Command` work?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's my first time developing sharepoint and i'm used to put the (). But thank you